# AttributeError: 'MapdlGrpc' object has no attribute 'load_parameters'

Tags: python, ansys, ansys-apdl

Pyansys load_parameters (): Has the official API of parameters () been changed? If so, what has it been changed to?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzDQQ.png)

When I ran the previous code, because the pyansys version at that time was very low (0.39.10), it may no longer be applicable in the current version, so I reported an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz8ca.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08pX5.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please add your code as text so that others can run your code. Links to the documentation of the package your using would also be useful.

Comment: sorry, the hole code is too long to cut, I can provide some code to help you understand

Answer (score 1):

I think that `load_parameters` has been replace by the `parameters` method; see this section in the **PyMAPDL** documentation:

https://mapdl.docs.pyansys.com/version/stable/api/_autosummary/ansys.mapdl.core.Mapdl.parameters.html

Sorry I can't even remember what `load_parameters` did, but if I had to guess it retrieved the MAPDL parameters to Python variables?  If this is what you mean to use then you can use the following style, assuming here that the MAPDL parameter name is `ARG1`:

```py
arg1 = mapdl.parameter["ARG1"]
```

Mike